# General PhoneGap overview information

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I'm new to mobile development and since I run a PC I plan to develop in Android. I wanted to fully understand the benefits of mobile framewors, particularly PhoneGap.

If I build an Android app using PhoneGap, can I easily port that to make an iOS app using PhoneGap build?

Does PhoneGap's api allow access to all the gestures and multitouch from the native applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I build an Android app using PhoneGap, can I easily port that to
>   make an iOS app using PhoneGap build?

yes, very easily as u just have to manage the js, html part of the app

> Does PhoneGap's api allow access to all the gestures and multitouch
>   from the native applications?

Thats not for phonegap to do. Phonegap just opens up a webview with your html in it. After that its just js and css. Use libraries like sencha touch or jquery mobile to harness gestures and touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's quite easy.

Once you've created your Android app you just need to create a PhoneGap project on Xcode and then copy/paste your www folder from your Android project to your iOS Project.

Then, maybe there will just be a few modifications to do to make it work but not that much.